# How to update from basic authentication to modern authentication using node-ews in node js application to send email ?So what are the things I need?

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices

I'm using node js application to send email by using node-ews ,as part of that I want update authentication from basic to modern OAuth2 .So what are the things I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is get an Access token so I'd suggest you use Microsoft Auth libraries https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-node-migration

Depending on the type of application you have eg is it a daemon app or a Interactive app will determine what type of Azure credentials flow you should use.

Once you have the token you just need to change the node-ews code to use it eg

```html
// exchange server connection info
const ewsConfig = {
  username: 'myuser@domain.com',
  token: 'oauth_token...',
  host: 'https://outlook.office365.com',
  auth: 'bearer'
};

// initialize node-ews
const ews = new EWS(ewsConfig);
```

One thing to be careful of is that library doesn't support any callbacks to check for token expiration. So if you have a process that runs for more the one hour you will need to deal with checking for the token expiration and getting a new token. I'd suggest you fork the library and modify the https://github.com/nmarus/node-ews/blob/master/lib/auth/bearer.js to include this if needed.